# Order By Parameter Firebird + C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-order-by, firebird

i am currently writting a method that reads date from a firebird database.
Here is the Header :

```
 public static void ReadInfo(int first, int skip,string orderBy)
```

That is my SQL Query :

```
const string SQL = "SELECT FIRST @first SKIP @skip A.ID,B.SHORTNAME, A.DATETIME, A.COMPUTERNAME,A.OSLOGIN, A.DBLOGIN, A.INFOTYPE, A.INFO FROM EVENTSGENERAL A JOIN EVENTSGENERATORS B ON B.GENERATOR_ = A.GENERATOR_ ORDER BY @orderBy";
```

And here is where i prepare the parameters for the query:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@first", FbDbType.Integer).Value = first;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@skip", FbDbType.Integer).Value = skip;
cmd.Parameters.Add ("@orderBy", FbDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = orderBy;
```

The problem is: The first two parameters work (first and skip are prepared correctly),i´ve tested it. But,the orderBy parameter raises an exeption once i try to run it :

```
{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -804\r\nData type unknown"}
```

I´ve tried to change toe FbDbType to "Text",but still not working.
Sorry about any bad english.
Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Just tried to:    cmd.Parameters.Add ( new FbParameter("@orderBy", FbDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = orderBy;

Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `order by` clause needs field specified you cant pass field name. What may work is if you make `@orderBy` parameter datatype integer and pass index of field. for example

```
select id, name from city order by 1 //this will order by id field
```

or if you programmatically edit sql statement like this:

```
string SQL = "SELECT FIRST @first SKIP @skip A.ID,B.SHORTNAME, A.DATETIME,
 A.COMPUTERNAME,A.OSLOGIN, A.DBLOGIN, A.INFOTYPE, A.INFO FROM EVENTSGENERAL A JOIN
 EVENTSGENERATORS B ON B.GENERATOR_ = A.GENERATOR_ ORDER BY {0}";
SQL = string.Format(SQL, orderBy);
```